# How to make the shortest date validator for all formats?

Tags: php, date, validation, date-formatting

I need to get data and format then return the `true` or `false` to check is the passed data have required date-format!

for example

```
var_dump(validateDateTime('Tue, 28 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', 'D, d M Y H:i:s O')); # the return value should be true
```

I want to validate the date in all formats,by getting the date and format and then return the result (true or false)

I still have this problem, any suggestion ?

Comment: I can't get the meaning of this question. What does "all formats" mean exactly? The format code combinations are infinite. And why does it matter that the validator is "short", with preference over being maintainable or performant?

Comment: I want to find the smartest way to validate the date

Comment: "Smart" can mean "29 Feb? Not leap year so user surely meant something else, I'll fix it for they". I suspect you're just learning the basics (which is fine) and you're unsure of how to build the feature altogether, but you're by no means after extreme optimisations of any kind. Am I right? You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), but don't forget to verify errors with [DateTime::getLastErrors()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php) (sorry, it's that quirky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following function to your application

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

then you can use it like so

```
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28 12:12:12')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-30 12:12:12')); # false
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28', 'Y-m-d')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('28/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('30/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # false
var_dump(validateDate('14:50', 'H:i')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14:77', 'H:i')); # false
var_dump(validateDate(14, 'H')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14', 'H')); # true
```